# Cybersource Hosted Order Page Integration

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud, cybersource

I want to integrate cybersource as a HOP i.e. the user will be redirected to the service provider to complete the payment. I am not able to find proper APIs for generating the hosted order pay for redirecting the user. Have gone through a documentation of Cybersource:

https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API.pdf

But it doesn't seems to be helpful. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better way to do this is through java script redirect.  You don't have
to use the gateway to host anything.

This method is completely PCI compliant in that it will keep you out of scope.

You generate the payment page from your web site and use a java script to
redirect PAN data to the payment server.

I don't know if Cyber Source supports this.  This is the same pattern that is
used by wallet payments.   Your Direct debit payments can use the same method even though PCI requirements do not apply there ( yet ).

If you want a sample java script to do this let me know